# Correct types for deep merge two nested objects (default config and customization)

Tags: typescript, merge

I have default config and I want to add option for user to be able to modify it

Here my code:

```js
const defaultConfig = {
  foo: 'bar',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'TOKEN',
    Locale: 'en-US'
  }
};

// modification for config from user
const changes = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Locale: null,
    Id: 2550
  }
};

// expected new config
const newConfig = {
  foo: 'bar',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'TOKEN',
    Locale: null,
    Id: 2550
  }
};

interface ExpectedNewConfig {
  foo: string;
  method: string;
  headers: {
    Authorization: string;
    Locale: null;
    Id: number;
  }
}
```

Function I use to deep merge:

```js
const merge = (obj1: any, obj2: any) => {
  Object
    .entries(obj2)
    .forEach(([k, v]) => {
      return obj1[k] = v === Object(v) ? merge(obj1[k] || {}, v) : v
    });
  return obj1;
};
```

Right now `merge` function returns `any` instead of correct merged types of `obj1` and `obj2`, I also couldn't manage to use generic, my attempt was to use `T, U` generic types and return `T & U` but it will return `never` for `headers`